PineScript Check Condition in the future candles~
I want to write a program that consists of several parts
When the first condition is true(met), the program should wait to check the next conditions in the candles that will be closed soon(in the future)
It means to check the continuation in the future of the market, not the past of the market
How should I write a program that can check the conditions in the future market candles?
for example:
I have a moving average 20 and a moving 50
I want when the bullish cross is formed, after seeing the bullishcross, my program will start to check the every future candles of the market and any candle that had a pullback to the moving 50 and its shadow would touch the moving 50 thats my signal and indicate it to me.
I need someone help me with an example of pinescript code

You need to look at the current bar and set a var flag if a certain event takes place. Then you wait for new bars to form and check for your additional condition and check the state of your flag.
Here is an example for you from the F.A.Q.
How can I save a value when an event occurs?
//@version=4
study("Save a value when an event occurs", "", true)
hiHi = highest(high, 5)[1]
var float priceAtCross = na
if crossover(close, hiHi)
    // When a cross occurs, save price. Since variable was declared with "var" keyword,
    // it will then preserve its value until the next reassignment occurs at the next cross.
    // Very important to use the ":=" operator here, otherwise we would be creating a second,
    // instance of the priceAtCross" variable local to the "if" block, which would disappear
    // once the "if" block was exited, and the global variable "priceAtCross"'s value would then not have changed.
    priceAtCross := close
plot(hiHi)
plot(priceAtCross, "Price At Cross", color.orange, 3, plot.style_circles)


Thank you for your explanation, but the way you said is not what I want
It may be necessary to check several conditions one after the other in the future
For example, the pullback that was done in the future, we should wait for a pin bar again in the next (future) candles and..
In addition, I need a complete example in the form of code, otherwise I know the explanations you gave in the comments of your codes, but the code is important to me.
Anyway, thank you for your reply

You just need several flags and need to understand how the execution model works.

@WinTer it is exactly as he wrote. You wait for Condition#1 and when it is met, you set Flag#1 to true. Then wait for Condition#2 and when that is met, you set Flag#2 to true and so on. When Flag#1+Flag#2+Flag#X are true, you have all of your condition as true. Whenever one of the Conditions is false, you invalidate all of your Flags and start over.
